# How are Richter magnitudes of past earthquakes estimated?

Tags: geophysics, seismology, earthquakes

In reading about historical major earthquakes, in particular, the [Great Shaanxi Earthquake](http://www.history.com/this-day-in-history/deadliest-earthquake-in-history-rocks-china) that killed approximately 830,000 people in July, 1556, there is a claim made about the approximate Richter scale magnitude:

> Later scientific investigation revealed that the magnitude of the quake was approximately 8.0 to 8.3

despite this earthquake obviously pre-dating the development of the Richter Scale.

**What do geologists look for to estimate the magnitude of past major earthquakes?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The approximate magnitude of ancient historic earthquakes may be estimated using a [Magnitude/Intensity comparison](http://earthquake.usgs.gov/learn/topics/mag_vs_int.php) based on modern earthquakes.  Earthquake intensity may be estimated from the descriptions written down by people. The Chinese officials made detailed records of the damage caused by large earthquakes.